Should a breaker panel with mild interior browning be replaced?
I recently had an electrician change a breaker, and when he took out the old breaker he said that I should consider changing the whole panel as he found some browning behind the breaker, on the metal behind it.  What I saw was almost imperceptible and I thought it appeared normal for a 30+ year old panel. He, however, was very adamant about changing the whole panel before a major catastrophe occurred.
Is this normal or is he right in his assessment?

Welcome. I revised your title to reflect what you're actually asking. I also removed your credential history and side story as they're not really relevant. Feel free to revise further, and take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. You might consider attaching a photo to your post.

I'm not even sure what "browning" is other than being overheated by a hot component.  Steel doesn't really care if it gets hot, not if it isn't structural.  Changing a panel is a multi-thousand-dollar job.

Browning as in burnt is not good. It usually is caused by loose connections. Some panel makes are known to be bad and recommended to be changed yesterday. Loose breaker connection plus heat stopping does go together. Electrical connections should be nice shiny clean. Dirt/rust/burn stains can cause extra heat. If just that breaker, with main breaker off you might clean it or move the breaker to an empty spot. Most of the panel, maybe listen to electrician.

I'd get additional opinions, especially for something as detailed and involved as a full panel replacement.

Can you post photos of the situation please?

A lot depends on the specifics. Certain panels have known problems, and in those cases the electrician should have used that as the reason, not "browning". Assuming it is a generally OK panel brand/type, then the question is where is the browning and why is there browning. A few possibilities:

Replacing a wrong-type breaker. In that case there may be browning on the bus bar because the old breaker did not fit correctly. Generally speaking that affects only that breaker space. And the solution is to NOT USE THAT BREAKER SPACE, not replace it with another breaker.
Replacing a failing or overstressed breaker - e.g., a breaker that tripped way too many times or was chronically used close to the limit (e.g., constant 20A on a 20A breaker - with continuous usage there is normally a derate to 80%).
Water damage - i.e., the browning is rust on the panel case. If there are no other problems and the water damage is old then it is likely not a real concern. If the water damage is ongoing then it needs to be resolved. And if the panel has damage more serious than a little surface rust (e.g., holes all the way through) then it should be replaced.

